# C# .net WebBrowser does not display page (Browser is not up to date)

Tags: c#, html, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

i'm trying to do a mini-bot for Ogame.

I run my **WebBrowser** class which says it is IE9 (WebBrowser.Version).

When I execute this:

```
wb.Navigate(www.ogame.com.us);
```

And it says:

```
"Your browser is not up to date."
```

However when I launch the page on Internet Explorer it DO displays the site.
Is it IE9 the WebBrowser embedded in **VisualStudio '12** with the **.NET framework 4.5**?
 Because I don't get it.
Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the real url is `http://www.ogame.us/` ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, shouldn't the URL be in quotes to make it a string?

Comment: You need to set up `Feature Control` for your `WebBrowser`, search SO for these words, it's been answered here many times here.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to emulate a different version of IE.
This is done via the registry.

```
internal class Helper
{
    public static void SetBrowserEmulation(
        string programName, IE browserVersion)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(programName))
        {
            programName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main" + 
                "\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
            if (regKey != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    regKey.SetValue(programName, browserVersion, 
                        RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error writing to the registry", ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software" + 
                        "\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main" + 
                        "\\FeatureControl", true);
                    regKey.CreateSubKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
                    regKey.SetValue(programName, browserVersion,
                        RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error accessing the registry", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal enum IE
{
    IE7 = 7000,
    IE8 = 8000,
    IE8StandardsMode = 8888,
    IE9 = 9000,
    IE9StandardsMode = 9999,
    IE10 = 10000,
    IE10StandardsMode = 10001
}
```

Calling this method.

```
Helper.SetBrowserEmulation(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, IE.IE10);
```

You need restart your program.